# NPM Command Line Tool - Command not working

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm working on a CLI tool. I'm using macOS. I was using `node index.js <command>` when running it locally. I decided to publish it as an npm package, but the command I've defined in the `bin` section of my `package.json` won't work.

In my `package.json`, i've defined `bin` as follows:

```
  "bin": {
    "scaffold": "index.js"
  },
```

I'm really not sure how to navigate this and quite unfamiliar. Would appreciate any help.

I've installed the package globally.

Tried to troubleshoot by running a few commands from posts, here are the results if they help:

Running `npm bin -g` results in:

```bash
Unknown command: "bin"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```

Running `npm root -g` results in:

```bash
/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules
```

Running `which scaffold` results in:

```bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/scaffold
```

Running `npm list -g project-scaffold` results in:

```bash
/opt/homebrew/lib
└── project-scaffold@1.1.1
```

Here's the package with the link to the repo and everything: https://www.npmjs.com/package/project-scaffold

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had a dumb if statement manually checking the first index of the argv array for the file path. This wouldn't work if switching from `node index.js <command>` to `scaffold <command>` because the first index no longer points to what the if statement is looking for, thereby never allowing runCLI() to run. Shame on me.

The culprit:

```js
if (process.argv[1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)) {
  runCLI();
}
```